# Object is possibly 'null' despite wrapping problem in if statement

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I have the following method in my Vue component:

```
dataURLtoBlob(dataurl: string): Blob {
    const arr: string[] = dataurl.split(",");
    if (arr) {
        if (arr[0]) {
            const mime = arr[0].match(/:(.*?);/)[1];
            const bstr = atob(arr[1]);
            let n = bstr.length;
            const u8arr = new Uint8Array(n);
            while (n--) {
                u8arr[n] = bstr.charCodeAt(n);
            }
            return new Blob([u8arr], { type: mime });
        }
    }

    return new Blob();
},
```

However, I receive the following typescript error despite wrapping the problematic line in a series of if statements:

```
81:34 Object is possibly 'null'.
    79 |             if (arr) {
    80 |                 if (arr[0]) {
  > 81 |                     const mime = arr[0].match(/:(.*?);/)[1];
       |                                  ^
    82 |                     const bstr = atob(arr[1]);
    83 |                     let n = bstr.length;
    84 |                     const u8arr = new Uint8Array(n);
```

**What am I doing incorrectly?**

Below is my tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "strict": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "types": [
      "webpack-env",
      "mocha",
      "chai"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "src/*"
      ]
    },
    "lib": [
      "esnext",
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "scripthost"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx",
    "src/**/*.vue",
    "tests/**/*.ts",
    "tests/**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not saying that `arr[0]` might be null, it's saying that `.match(/:(.*?);/)` might return null. So to check for this would be:

```
const match = arr[0].match(/:(.*?);/);
if (match) {  
  const mime = match[1];
  // ... the rest of the code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can change
from `arr[0].match(/:(.*?);/)[1];`
to `arr[0].match(/:(.*?);/)?[1];`

it is coming from second index, not the first one.

Answer (score 0):

I could rewrite it this way

```
dataURLtoBlob(dataurl: string): Blob {
    const arr: string[] = dataurl.split(',');

    // fail fast
    if(!Array.isArray(arr) || !arr[0] || !arr[1])
        return new Blob();
    // can change this to const if you are not planning to set a default mimetype
    let mime = arr[0].match(/:(.*?);/)[1];
    // or you can force typescript compiler to consider this as (string or whatever is the type) with type casting as follow
    // const mime = <string>arr[0].match(/:(.*?);/)[1];
    // const mime = arr[0].match(/:(.*?);/)[1] as string; whatever you like
    if(!mime)
    // mime = 'default mime' in case you have a default mime type
    // or return new Blob() or anything you plan to do in case mime type does not exist

    const bstr = atob(arr[1]);
    let n = bstr.length;
    const u8arr = new Uint8Array(n);

    while (n--) {
        u8arr[n] = bstr.charCodeAt(n);
    }

    return new Blob([u8arr], { type: mime });  
}
```

This way you don't end up with deep level nested blocks which usually is hard to read.